# Indian National Olympiad $2000$ Problem $6$

Tags: solution-verification, contest-math

> For any natural numbers $n$, ( $n \geq 3$), let $f(n)$ denote the number of non-congruent integer-sided triangles with perimeter $n$. Show that
> (i) $f(1999) > f (1996)$;
> (ii) $f(2000) = f(1997)$.

**My proof outline** -

for second part -

Let $a,b,c$ be three integer sides for the triangle with perimeter $2000$ then $$a+b+c=2000$$ and by triangular inequality we have that $a+b>c,b+c>a,c+a>b$ so we get that $a,b,c<1000$

Now applying the formula of stars and bars we get that we have a total of ${1000\choose2}$ and since we wwant non congruent we divide this by $3$ ,similarly we do for $f(1997)$ but here answer is coming  ${999\choose2}$ .

So how $f(2000)=f(1997)$

Someone pls point out where is the mistake ?

thankyou

Comment: I don't see the mistake but if $a+b+c=1997$ then $(a+1)+(b+1)+(c+1)=2000$.

Comment: Try to define an injective map from the set of such triangles of perimeter 1997 to the set of such triangles with perimeter 2000 and see if it is surjective

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot rely on stars and bars. Stars and bars counts $\{a=600,b=650,c=750\}$ and $\{a=600,b=750,c=650\}$ as separate and in this case these values will permute in $3!=6$ ways, not $3$. On the other hand $\{600,700,700\}$ permutes in $3!/2!=3$ ways, not $6$. So it is clear that you can't obtain the answer by dividing by $3$ (or $6$).

---

We will denote a triangle by the unordered set containing its sides $\{a,b,c\}$. Let $A_n$ be the set of integer sided non-congruent triangles of perimeter $n$. Then $f(n)=|A_n|$. Define a map$$g:A_{1996}\to A_{1999}\\g(\{a,b,c\})=\{a+1,b+1,c+1\}$$Since $a+b>c\implies (a+1)+(b+1)>(c+1),g$ is well defined.

This map is injective, since$$g(\{a_1,b_1,c_1\})=g(\{a_2,b_2,c_2\})=\{p,q,r\}\\\implies \{a_1,b_1,c_1\}=\{a_2,b_2,c_2\}=\{p-1,q-1,r-1\}$$Thus $f(1999)\ge f(1996)$.

---

We now try to find a triangle in $A_{1999}$ that is not in $g(A_{1996})$. Let such a triangle be $\{a,b,c\}$, then$$a+b+c=1999\tag{1}$$and $\{a-1,b-1,c-1\}\not\in A_{1996}$. Since the perimeter of $\{a-1,b-1,c-1\}=1999-3=1996$, we require the triangular inequality to fail for $\{a-1,b-1,c-1\}$ i.e.$$(a-1)+(b-1)-(c-1)\le0\implies a+b-c\le 1$$Since $\{a,b,c\}\in A_{1999},a+b-c>0$. This gives$$a+b-c=1\tag{2}$$since $a,b,c$ are integral.

$c=999,a=500=b$ is a solution of $(1),(2)$. Hence we get $f(1999)>f(1996)$.

---

We can define a similar injection $g_1$ from $A_{1997}\to A_{2000}$. But we run into an issue when we try to find a triangle in $A_{2000}$ that is not in $g_1(A_{1997})$. Equations $(1),(2)$ get modified as$$a+b+c=2000\tag{1'}$$$$a+b-c=1\tag{2'}$$Adding these two we get $2(a+b)=2001$ which is not possible. Hence $f(2000)=f(1997)$.

Comment: Honestly, now where did you talk about the mistake OP is asking for?

Comment: @VishaalSudarsan Fixed.

Comment: It’s okay :)...and hey I wanted to appologize for our last interaction.

Comment: Nevermind that. Raat gai baat gai ;)

Comment: Hahah, thanks ya :)

Answer (score 0):

You have misapplied stars and bars here. The quantity $\binom{1000}{2}$ partitions 1001 elements into three pieces. If you wanted to compute $f(2000)$,  you want to partition 2000 elements into three pieces, where each partition has at most 999 elements. Furthermore, to remove double-counting, you cannot simply divide by 3, since for example $(1,1,1)$ is unique for triangles of perimeter $3$.

I would suggest that a different approach be taken. Instead of attempting to compute $f(1997)$ or $f(2000)$ (and similarly for the first part of the exercise), find a way to map a triangle of the smaller perimeter to a triangle of the larger perimeter.

Hint: If $T_n$ denotes the set of sidelengths of such triangles with perimeter $n$, and $(a,b,c) \in T_n$, then $(a+1, b+1, c+1) \in T_{n+3}$. Now try to invert this correspondence. In particular, show why the inversion fails for $n = 1996$ but succeeds for $n = 1997$.

Comment: I think it’s easier the other way around, that is a map from (a,b,c) to (a-1,b-1,c-1)... and show how it fails for a=1 for 1999 but not for 2000. What are your thoughts?

Comment: Sure, that's the "inversion" that I was referring to. But I agree that perhaps it is easier to think of it as the primary map.